# Unordered selection implementation based on std::set ends up having duplicates

Tags: c++, set, stdset

Trying to implement a combination of 4 objects taken 2 at a time without taking into account the arrangement (such must be considered duplicates: so that order is not important) of objects with `std::set` container:

```
struct Combination {
    int m;
    int n;
    Combination(const int m, const int n):m(m),n(n){}
};
const auto operator<(const auto & a, const auto & b) {
    //explicitly "telling" that order should not matter:
    if ( a.m == b.n && a.n == b.m ) return false;
    //the case "a.m == b.m && a.n == b.n" will result in false here too:
    return a.m == b.m ? a.n < b.n : a.m < b.m;
}
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::set< Combination > c;
    for ( short m = 0; m < 4; ++ m ) {
    for ( short n = 0; n < 4; ++ n ) {
        if ( n == m ) continue;
        c.emplace( m, n );
    } }
    std::cout << c.size() << std::endl; //12 (but must be 6)
}
```

The expected set of combinations is `0 1`, `0 2`, `0 3`, `1 2`, `1 3`, `2 3` which is 6 of those, but resulting `c.size() == 12`. Also, my `operator<(Combination,Combination)` does satisfy `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a) means elements are equal` requirement.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can't work<sup>1</sup>, because your `operator<` does not introduce a *strict total ordering*. One requirement for a strict total ordering is that, for any three elements `a`, `b` and `c`

```
a < b
```

and

```
b < c
```

imply that

```
a < c
```

(in a mathematical sense). Let's check that. If we take

```
Combination a(1, 3);
Combination b(1, 4);
Combination c(3, 1);
```

you see that

```
a < b => true
b < c => true
```

but

```
a < c => false
```

---

If you can't order the elements you can't use `std::set`. A [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) seems to more suited for the task. You just need a `operator==` to compare for equality, which is trivial and a hash function that returns the same value for elements that are considere identical. It could be as simple as adding `m` and `n`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, maybe it *could* work, or not, or both, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, it explains a lot. How do you know it though? Is it stated anywhere in **std** docs? Couldn't find [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) nor [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Comment: Yes, it's (somewhat hidden) stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (first paragraph, second sentence) that _"Sorting is done using the key comparison function Compare."_ and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) you can find the requirements of compare (`comp(a, b)`)

Comment: Indeed, missed that one: `if comp(a,b)==true and comp(b,c)==true then comp(a,c)==true`, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Attached is the working code. The tricky part that you were missing was not adding a section of code to iterate through the already working set to then check the values. You were close! If you need a more thorough answer I will answer questions in the comments. Hope this helps!

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std; 

struct Combination {
    int m;
    int n;
    Combination(const int m, const int n):m(m),n(n){}
};
const auto operator<(const auto & a, const auto & b) {
    //explicitly "telling" that order should not matter:
    if ( a.m == b.n && a.n == b.m ) return false;
    //the case "a.m == b.m && a.n == b.n" will result in false here too:
    return a.m == b.m ? a.n < b.n : a.m < b.m;
}


int main() {
    set< Combination > c;
    for ( short m = 0; m < 4; ++ m ) 
    {
         for ( short n = 0; n < 4; ++ n ) 
          { 
                //Values are the same we do not add to the set
                if(m == n){

                    continue; 
                }
                else{
                   Combination s(n,m);  

                   const bool is_in = c.find(s) != c.end();
                   if(is_in == true){

                       continue; 
                   }
                   else{
                       cout << " M: " << m << " N: " << n << endl; 
                       c.emplace( m, n); 
                   }

                }
          } 
    }

    cout << c.size() << endl; //16 (but must be 6)


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is that I don't want to check container already holding the value I'm inserting, because that's the intention of using it (sample code ripped off of complicated project where I intended to rely on such `std::set` property). That's how `std::set` is defined: [std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type Key](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [Sets are containers that store unique elements following a specific order](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/).

Comment: ... so when I emplace/insert any elements into `std::set` I want to rely on it holding only unique elements by it's property, not by adding another code on top of it.